# Object Initialisation performance

Tags: php, performance, benchmarking

My question sounds really simple but I wasn't able to find an answer on the Internet.

Let's assume you have a class having some attributes. Is there any performance difference between initialization of an empty object and changing the values of the variables later:

```
$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->value1 = 1;
$obj->value2 = 2;
```

and the creation of a constructor which basically does the same thing:

```
class MyClass
{
    public $value1;
    public $value2;

    public function __construct($val1, $val2)
    {
        $this->value1 = $val1;
        $this->value2 = $val2;
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass(1,2);
```

Please don't think about code readability and best practices :)

Comment: Personally, I'm sure it doesn't matter, but go ahead and generate 100 classes and then create them multiple times in a loop and benchmark it.

Comment: I would expect the differences to be non-existent or negligible - however, the only way to find out is to benchmark.

Comment: The difference would be so trivial as to hardly matter at all. This *is* all about best-practices, hardly about performance.

Comment: I think it is better to use a constructor, which would allow you to specify a default value, but more importantly, to *enforce* them. If you really want to know, just try it in a loop to benchmark it ;)

Comment: There is a reason that Knuth once said "*premature optimisation is the root of all evil*": trying to answer questions like this leads people to making design choices that sacrifice correctness for some perceived (often immaterial and sometimes negative) performance advantage.  **Don't let performance motivate your design decisions**: first get it right and *only then* make adjustments to get it within your requisite performance bounds.

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity, I ran some quick benchmarks on my own machine - comparing 100 iterations of each. Running the script 8 times indicates to me that their performance, as we all assumed, is basically identical.

Comment: The performance difference, if any, is likely to be so small that a benchmark will not register it unless the code is run many thousands of times. You've likely already spent more time worrying about it than you will likely ever save by using the "more efficient" version for the rest of your life. +1 for preemptive optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for fun I tried 1 000 000 iterations with this resultats:

in constructor

> lukashes@biorobot:/tmp/php$ php in.php
>
> string(13) "1012924.416kb"
>
> string(18) "2.2154049873352sec"

out of constuctor

> lukashes@biorobot:/tmp/php$ php out.php
>
> string(12) "996933.632kb"
>
> string(18) "2.0962958335876sec"

Note: I am save all 1 000 000 instances.

Comment: +1 This (unsurprisingly) shows that the burden of pushing/popping arguments on the stack is negligible, but nonetheless non-zero.  All that one needs to add now is an analysis into the impact on correctness & maintainability of allowing objects to be constructed without members being initialised.